# Mobile App Authentication with Rails webservice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing `webservice` for a Mobile app.

Now My Clients requirement is that `authentication` of `API` should be done by `An Access Key` which will come along with Webservice call. And that access Key will change according to session.

I searched many places and found some of the article and railscast that Oauth or Some of the article is suggesting that cancan gem can also act as `Role based management`.

**But I need authentication for that particular access key.**

Please give some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Devise.secure_compare method. Create a User model with field api_token:string. Create user and generate random, unique api_token. Pass those api_token in API request params.

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :parse_request, :authenticate_user_from_token!

 private
   def authenticate_user_from_token!
     if !@json['api_token']
       render nothing: true, status: :unauthorized
     else
       @user = nil
       User.find_each do |u|
         if Devise.secure_compare(u.api_token, @json['api_token'])
           @user = u
         end
       end
     end
   end

   def parse_request
     @json = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
   end
 end
```

All API's controllers will inherit from ApiController

```
 class ProjectsController < ApiController

 end
```

Comment: Can you pls give me some link which will having tutorial like explanation.
So that i can start with devise with api_token from scratch
and only found devise tutorial in railscast which is not telling about this authentication 
pls shared me some link. it will be very helpful

Comment: This tutorial give you better understanding of authentication in API call.  [https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/building-a-restful-api-in-a-rails-application]